# $\frac{d}{dz}$ and $\frac{d}{d\overline{z}}$ for $|z-a|^p$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I wish to find $\frac{d}{dz}$ and $\frac{d}{d\overline{z}}$ of $f(z)=|z|$ and $|z-a|^p$, $-\infty < p < \infty$.

$\frac{d}{dz} = \frac{1}{2} \left ( \frac{du}{dx} + \frac{dv}{dy}\right ) + \frac{1}{2}\left ( \frac{dv}{dx} - \frac{du}{dy}\right )$

$\frac{d}{d\overline{z}} = \frac{1}{2} \left ( \frac{du}{dx} - \frac{dv}{dy}\right ) + \frac{i}{2}\left ( \frac{dv}{dx} + \frac{du}{dy}\right )$

How does this work for $|z-a|^{p}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT:**

Write $|z|=(z\bar z)^{1/2}$ and $|z-a|^p=(z-a)^{p/2}(\bar z-\bar a)^{p/2}$

Then, take partial derivatives with respect to $z$ and $\bar z$.

**SPOLIER ALEERT** Scroll over the highlighted area to reveal the answer

> We have the transformation $(x,y)\to (z,\bar z)$ as given by $$z=x+iy$$and $$\bar z=x-iy$$and the inverse transformation $(z,\bar z) \to (x,y)$ as given by $$x=\frac12 (z+\bar z)$$and $$y=\frac{1}{2i}(z-\bar z)$$Then, from the chain-rule, we can write $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=\frac12\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\right)+\frac i2\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right) \tag 1$$along with $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z}=\frac12\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\right)+\frac i2\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)\tag 2$$We note that if $f$ is analytic, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z}=0$ and thus, $(2)$ yields the Cauchy-Riemann equations.  Now, if $f=|z-a|^p$, we have $f=(z-a)^{p/2}(\bar z-\bar a)^{p/2}$ and $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=\frac p2(z-a)^{p/2-1}(\bar z-\bar a)^{p/2}=\frac p2 (\bar z-\bar a)|z-a|^{p-2}$$Alternatively, we can use $(1)$ to calculate $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$.  Noting that the $v=0$, we have $$\begin{align}\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}&=\frac12 \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-\frac i2 \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\\\\&=\frac p2 (x-a_r) |z-a|^{p-2}-i\frac12 (y-a_i)|z-a|^{p-2}\\\\&=\frac p2 (\bar z-\bar a)|z-a|^{p-2} \end{align}$$as expected!  A parallel development is straightforward for evaluating $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z}$ and is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: for d/dz of |z-a|^p, |z-a|^p = (z-a)^{p/2}(z* - a*)^{p/2}. I am going to assume the exercise means that a is complex. So we have (x+iy-a)^{p/2} (x-iy-a*)^{p/2}. How do we simplify this so I can follow the formula for d/dz ?

Comment: Actually, one need not use the "formulae."

Comment: Dr, is $\frac{d}{dv} = \frac{p}{2}(z-a)^{\frac{p}{2} - 1}$ ?

Comment: Not quite. $\frac{df}{dz} =\frac p2 (z-a)^{p/2-1}(\bar z-\bar a)^{p/2}=\frac p2 (\bar z-\bar a)|z-a|^{p-2}$.

Comment: Thank you. Why are we allowed to take the derivative with respect to z (and with z* in the next part of the exercise) like a normal derivative? Are you sure we don't have to apply cauchys differentiation formula?

Comment: Yes.  $z$ and $\bar z$ are independent variables.

Comment: do we call $z$ an independent variable if $z=x+iy$ ?

Comment: @Rdua I added a "Spoiler Alert" section that shows the equivalence of two methodologies for evaluating $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$.  It explains that we have a bilateral transformation from/to $(x,y)$ and $(z,\bar z)$.  Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Comment: Dr, your "spoiler" was great help and I understand now. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.